# Practical question: Temperature sensitive device, insulating or add more thermal mass?

Tags: analog, sensor, heat, thermal, heatsink

If I have a very sensitive photodiode/sensor/analog front end part of a circuit that can be sensitive to temperature and the device does not draw much power (for example, a small photodiode,) what is the best method of keeping its temperature stable?
Is it better to add insulation or thermal mass through a heat sink?

On the reverse side: If it is drawing a little bit of power, enough to raise its temperature by 1C, is adding insulation or adding thermal mass better for temperature stability?

I have seen voltage reference circuits have heaters as well, but of course that is integrated.

Comment: What kind of environment are you talking about?  The answer is a lot different for a deep space probe vs something in the lab.

Comment: The best way is to add a temperature controlled heater, with the set point slightly above the maximum expected ambient temperature.

Comment: @SteveSh Assuming ambient room temp

Comment: Ovenised devices like oscillators and sensors are a thing [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oven). You could design a simple analog PID control for keeping a stable temperature using wire-wound resistors or a film heater. For guarding the device, you would typically put the device inside a custom ceramic enclosure with a metallic sleeve. There are other techniques for temperature tracking where you put your temperature-sensitive device in spatial contact with its current source so that the output signal is self-compensated, however, it does not work as good as a proper control circuit

Comment: @Jirhska Yes, photodiodes are highly sensitive to ambient -- doubling dark current every +10 C, for example. Are you placing a reverse voltage across the photodiode? What I've done in the past where it mattered is to place the photodiode on a small TEC stack (cool, not warm, was important) and kept inside something that looks like a TO-5 package with a quartz window. I also included the 1st stage front end inside so that signals leaving were large enough. (I was at fempto-amp current levels, so it mattered.)

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by 'temperature stability'.

The device will have a time constant with respect to ambient. We can model the situation electrically as the thermal mass of the diode being a capacitance, and the thermal resistance to ambient being a resistance. This will have a time constant of RC.

Adding thermal mass increases C. Adding insulation increases R. Both increase the time constant RC.

When the ambient changes, a longer time constant means that

- the device will slew to the new ambient temperature more slowly
- it will still get to the new temperature eventually

When the device dissipation changes

- it will take longer to stabilise to its final temperature
- insulation will not affect the initial rate at which it changes temperature
- higher thermal mass will reduce the initial rate at which it changes temperature

What people generally mean by 'temperature stability' is that the ambient can change, and the device dissipation can change, and the device temperature doesn't. As you can see from the above, changing the device time constant with either insulation or thermal mass does neither.

However, there are circumstances where short term stability, or slowing down the rate of change, is useful. Taking two readings in quick succession to look for changes.

There are two ways generally used to get long term thermal stability. The traditional way is an oven. You choose a device temperature at least 10 C above your highest expected ambient, and heat the device to that, with a thermostat. Adding insulation reduces the power you need to keep the device at that temperature, removing thermal mass reduces the time it takes the oven to get to its correct operating temperature. Too high a device temperature accelerates ageing, too low restricts the maximum operating ambient.

Now that Peltiers are economically available, a newer method is to use one between the device and heat sink. As it's capable of both heating and cooling, the device can be controlled to room temperature, or whatever temperature is best to operate at.